# Calculating Percentage of qualified and disqualified leads in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: report, dynamics-crm

I have to create a report in dynamics crm for calculating the percentage of leads qualified and disqualified.

I can count the number of qualified and disqualified leads using grouping in reports but cant find any way to calculate percentage.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using CRM report wizard. You'll have to export your report as .rdl file and open it in visual studio. Then add additional field and calculate it by setting it's expression to something like: =(QualifiedLeads)/(All leads) - depending on the values in the wizard generated columns.  You can then set the format of this field to "Percentage".

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have 2 columns in your recordset - Lead Type (Qualified or Disqualified) and Count (LeadsCount field). To make 3-rd column that will show percentage you will have to use something like following formula:

```
=FormatPercent(Field!LeadsCount.Value/Sum(Field!LeadsCount.Value),1)
```

Also you can find a lot of helpful information using search engines - http://tinyurl.com/h8ot75b